# Accept " as input from user in a .BAT File?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, command, prompt

How do I make the code ask the user to input `cd "folder one"` then accept their input once they correctly input the test and go to label `:2`.

```
@echo off

:BEGIN
echo cd "folder one" = navigates user to folder 1.
set /p input=Insert Word:
if /i "%input%"=="cd "folder on""  goto 2
if /i not "%input%"=="cd "folder one"" & goto BEGIN
echo.

:2
echo you did it!
timeout /t 05
exit
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, it should be `goto BEGIN`, not `& goto BEGIN`. So, your question is to check the user input (simply a variable), with a value? This is so simple...

Comment: You have nested `"`s. Try `[%input%]==[cd "folder on"]`. See [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) why `"` can cause problems here.

Comment: Typo: `folder on` is used instead `folder one`.

Comment: @DavidPostill the correction doesn't work, assuming I did it correctly. 
----
:BEGIN
echo cd "folder one" = navigates user to folder 1.
set /p input=Insert Word:
if /i [%input%]==[cd "folder on"] goto 2
if /i not [%input%]==[cd "folder one"] goto BEGIN
echo.
:2
echo you did it!
timeout /t 05
exit

Comment: @DavidPostill spaces are a command separator. The only way to protect them is with double quotes. The IF command does not see the angle brackets as the beginning and end of the string to compare.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that; you need to escape inner double quotes. You can try:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:BEGIN
echo cd "folder one" = navigates user to folder 1.
set /p input=Insert Word: 
set input1=cd "folder one"
if /I !input! == !input1! (goto 2) else (goto BEGIN)
echo.

:2
echo you did it^^!
timeout /t 5
exit
```

Using here `DelayedExpansion` due to percent sign symbol which causes double quotes not to be read correctly.

Comment: It now accepts quotes, However if I even type "a"  and press enter, it echoes "you did it!" back to me. therefore, the user does not have to type the correct string to get a successful echo message in your .bat file, how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:BEGIN
echo cd "folder one" = navigates user to folder 1.
set "item1=cd "folder one""
set /p "input=Insert Word: "
if /i "!input!" == "!item1!" (goto 2) else goto BEGIN

:2
echo you did it^^!
timeout /t 05
exit /b
```

Delayed expansion of variables can help with these cases,
as pre-expanded variables are expanded literally into the
source prior to execution. Delayed expansion stores the value
in memory and compares the value direct at execution.

To ensure correct comparison, both sides may need to be delayed
expansion to avoid special character such as double quotes.
Both sides may not need the outer double quotes as it does not
suffer the literal syntax error issues of the pre-expanded
variables. I chose to add the outer double quotes.

You may need to disable delayed expansion if you use
pre-expanded variables at expand time, that may contain
exclaimation marks, and enable after that time to expand
the delayed expanded variables.

View `setlocal /?` about the use of `enabledelayedexpansion`
and `disabledelayedexpansion`.